# wondering why my list has bigger number than second argument function return False?

Tags: python

```
def greater(list, num)
    for x in list:
        if x > num:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

as you can see in my code, i am trying to write a function that return True if list_number contained number that is bigger than second argument, otherwise return False.
but here is confusing:
when i input:  `greater([1, 2, 3], 2)`, and its return `False`. I am wondering why is that? the first argument contained 3 and its bigger than 2.

any helps and explanations will be appreciated.

Comment: Try placing `return False` **after** the for loop

Comment: Only your first element will be considered since you return on the first iteration.

Comment: `return any(i > number for i in list_number)`

Comment: @KlausD.cool, can you explain why only first element will be considered? and how does else stopped the loop?

Comment: You hit the first `return` and the function ends. There's no way not to hit a `return` for any element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have it return at the end of the function. Right now, you have it return after checking *only the first number*. Try this:

```
def has_gt(list_number,number):
    for x in list_number:
        if x > number:
            return True
    
    return False
```

A property of if/else is that if one runs, the other doesn't. But in both cases, one runs. In your code, this snippet:

```
        if x > number:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Means that it will check if the number is bigger than the number in question. If it is, it will return True. If not, it will return False. A return call instantly ends the processing of a function, so it will stop checking after that.

To summarize, your code loops through the target list. It checks the first number, one, and sees if it is bigger than two. It is not, so the code returns False, instantly ending the function. So, your function just ended in a False, which is what it returned.

The change I made was that it returns False at the end of the code. This means that it will check *each* value for being greater than the target. If it finds *any* value greater than the target, it will end processing, with a return value of True. If the code hasn't returned by the time it reaches the end of the function, it will return False because of the statement at the end of the function.

Comment: thanks for answer, but can you please explain in detail of why it is only checking the first number? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually what happens is the else part also runs just after comparing the `number` (here 2) with the first element in the `list_number` (here 1) thus returns `false`.

So the solution is you need to let the for loop first run completely which is stopped by the else statement.

```
 def has_gt(list_number,number):
    for x in list_number:
        if x > number:
            return True
    
    return False
```

Comment: thank you, but can you please explain more details of why it only checking first element and stopped?

Comment: As per loop is concerned, a loop runs the code inside it and then moves back to the top. So when it checks for the first condition i.e, 1 and 2 against each other, as 1 is less than 2,so if condition is not satisfied and it moves to else statement which then returns false. And as something is returned, function simply stops.

Comment: BTW can you please explain why you unmarked my answer as accepted??